# Does Windows Task Scheduler behave strange?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, task-scheduler, windows-server-2003

I made my application  (WinForms EXE) that when I launch it my from command-line or GUI, I see an icon in the systary and it's OK.

I see now that if I wrap my application in a task into the Task Scheduler on Windows 2008 R2 or Windows 7, it's running in background but I see nothing in the systray. I'd prefer to see the icon in the tray.

Since the application is just running the same on both ways, I'm wondering what could be the reason I can't see the icon on systray?
I want to see icon on the systray when it is launched from Task Scheduler too.

Thank you

Comment: Have you got your task set to 'Run only when the user is logged on' ?

Comment: Does the task run at Start Up - If so try adding a 2 minute delay to the task.

Comment: Thank you. I've just learned the "/IT" parameter. Still I have this problem on Windows Server 2003 - altought this parameter was not exist yet. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I presume you are using SchTasks. The /IT parameter is certainly on Windows 2003 R2, so I find it strange it would not be on Windows 2003. You could try creating the job using the older AT command (which still exists) and use the /Interactive parameter or you could try amending the task via the Control Panel.